# Hibernate Search Order by child-count

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

Consider:

```
@Indexed
@Entity
public class TParent  implements java.io.Serializable {

 .....
 private Set<TChild> TChildSet = new HashSet<TChild>(0);

 @ContainedIn
 @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="TParent")
 public Set<TChild> getTChildSet() {
     return this.TChildSet;
 }
```

A query would be something like this:

```
FullTextQuery hibQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery( luceneQuery );
hibQuery.setSort( ... )
```

How can a sort-by-child-count be achieved?

In other words, the order of the TParent list returned would be dictated by the TChildSet count.

I know an
    @Formula
can be used in SQL circumstances. I'm not sure if something similar can be used for Lucene?

Any help, pointers, comments even critique welcome.

Thanks Very Much
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In hibernate search, you can make a custom [Bridge](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.4/reference/en-US/html/search-mapping.html#search-mapping-bridge) for this purpose.

Something along the lines of:

```
@FieldBridge(impl = com.myco.myapp.CollectionCountBridge.class)
@ContainedIn
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="TParent")
public Set<TChild> getTChildSet() {
     return this.TChildSet;
}
```

With the custom bridge implementation:

```
public class CollectionCountBridge extends PaddedIntegerBridge {

    @Override
    public String objectToString(Object object) {
        if (object == null || (!(object instanceof Collection))) {
            return null;
        }
        Collection<?> coll = (Collection<?>) object;
        return super.objectToString(coll.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much Don, that's really helpful, really appreciate it. To get it to work I had to use IntegerBridge instead of PaddedIntegerBridge which didn't seem available to me (HS v4.2.0).  All works great except, when I add a new TChild (the bridge code is invoked and i can see the collection size incremented) the sort doesn't update until I rebuild the index. To get the Bridge code to invoke when a new TChild is added I added @Field(analyse = Analyse.No) to the getTChildSet() method. Any ideas why the sort-order didn't change? Thanks.

Comment: Following up the 2nd part of this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847238/hibernate-search-custom-bridge-value-not-updating