# Hibernate Search Order by Collection Count within Date Range

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I have two objects - a `Document` object, and a `Hit` object:

```
Document
    id
    description
    hits (Collection of type Hits)
    ...

Hit
    documentId (Type Document)
    date
    ...
```

I'm attempting to create a Hibernate Search query that searches the document description, then orders the results by the count of hits within a given date range.

I'm having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around how to do this. I've taken a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827149/hibernate-search-order-by-child-count), but it takes into account the total number of hits, and does not allow for dynamic date range queries, as the bridged field is updated independent of date.

I currently have an index for my `Document` object with searching on `description` working fine. I'm thinking I may need to create an index for the `Hit` object, run a query against it for the date range, group by `documentId`, and then run a second query using the searched term against the `Document` index.

Given this strategy, I'm still not sure how to:

1. group the hits by `documentId`
2. maintain the order of the results from the hits query
3. handle pagination.

My guess is that I would need to get all results from the `Hits` index (using some type of faceting logic for grouping/ordering maybe?), then match on `documentId`/term and handle pagination in the second query. I'm just not sure how all of this would look when it comes to building a query with the [QueryBuilder](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.3/api/org/hibernate/search/query/dsl/QueryBuilder.html) interface, or if there's a completely different way to approach this that I haven't thought of.

**UPDATE**

```
public class DateRangeDownloadsFieldComparator extends FieldComparator<Integer> {

    class DownloadsParser implements FieldCache.IntParser {

        @Override
        public int parseInt(String string) {
           /* 
            * What do I pass here and what do I do with it? 
            * Ideally, I would pass the downloads collection and return the size of the
            * collection where the download appears within the provided date range, but 
            * passing a collection here does nothing, as it's silently ignored.
            */

            return 0;
        }
    }

    private Calendar startDate;

    private Calendar endDate;

    private final int[] fieldValues;

    private int bottom;

    private int[] currentReaderValues;

    public DateRangeDownloadsFieldComparator(int numHits, Calendar startDate, Calendar endDate) {

        super();
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;

        fieldValues = new int[numHits];
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(int slot1, int slot2) {

        return compareValues(fieldValues[slot1], fieldValues[slot2]);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareBottom(int doc) throws IOException {

        int currentDoc = currentReaderValues[doc];

        return compareValues(bottom, currentDoc);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareValues(Integer v1, Integer v2) {

        if (v1 > v2) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (v1 < v2) {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void copy(int slot, int doc) throws IOException {

        int v1 = currentReaderValues[doc];
        fieldValues[slot] = v1;

    }

    @Override
    public void setBottom(int slot) {

        bottom = fieldValues[slot];

    }

    @Override
    public void setNextReader(IndexReader reader, int docBase) throws IOException {

        currentReaderValues = FieldCache.DEFAULT
                .getInts(reader, "downloads", new DownloadsParser());
    }

    @Override
    public Integer value(int slot) {

        return fieldValues[slot];
    }

}
```

**UPDATE 2**

**Document Entity**

```
@Entity                                                                                                                                
@Table(name = "documents")                                                                                                             
@Indexed(index = "documents")                                                                                                          
public class EDocument {                                                                                                               

    public static final String FIELD_NAME = "name";                                                                                    

    public static final String FIELD_CREATED = "created";                                                                              

    public static final String FIELD_DESCRIPTION = "description";                                                                      

    @Id                                                                                                                                
    @GeneratedValue                                                                                                                    
    @Column(name = "id")                                                                                                               
    private Long id;                                                                                                                   

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)                                                                                                  
    @Column(name = "created")                                                                                                          
    @Field(name = FIELD_CREATED)                                                                                                       
    private Calendar created;                                                                                                          

    @Column(name = "name")                                                                                                             
    @Field(name = FIELD_NAME)                                                                                                          
    private String name;                                                                                                               

    @Column(name = "description")                                                                                                      
    @Field(name = FIELD_DESCRIPTION)                                                                                                   
    private String description;                                                                                                        

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)                                                                                                 
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)                                                                                    
    @IndexedEmbedded(depth = 1)                                                                                                        
    private EUser user;                                                                                                                

    @OneToMany(                                                                                                                        
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,                                                                                                    
            targetEntity = EDownload.class,                                                                                            
            mappedBy = "document",                                                                                                     
            orphanRemoval = true,                                                                                                      
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)                                                                                                 
    @IndexedEmbedded(depth = 1)                                                                             
    private Set<EDownload> downloads;                                                                                                  

    public EDocument() {                                                                                                               

        created = Calendar.getInstance();                                                                                              
    }                                                                                                                                  

    // getters and setters                                                                                                             

}
```

**Download Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "downloads")
public class EDownload {

    public static final String FIELD_REQUESTED = "requested";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "requested")
    @Field(name = FIELD_REQUESTED)
    private Calendar requested;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "document_id", nullable = false)
    private EDocument document;

    public EDownload() {

        requested = Calendar.getInstance();
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Unless your search for Hit can change the number of documents return, I would use second query in hibernate to get order by hit counts. So, you search the description and get a list of document id (projection), and then do second query (native or hql) passing in the document ids? Lucene/Hibernate search is good for boolean search of text, but not ideal for your second specific scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with something similar to what @gmansoor suggested - a first query for the terms, which returns IDs, and then a second query based on those IDs. It doesn't appear that there's a way to do this in a single query in Hibernate Search, so this seems to be the best solution for now. If anyone knows of a better way to do this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I probably would index the hits as part of the document index using `@IndexedEmbedded`. Then you run your query against the `description` field, providing a custom `Sort` implementation. The custom sort will need the data range as parameter and then count the hits in this date range and order accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would you mind pointing me in the direction of some documentation on creating a custom Sort? My searches aren't turning up anything.

Comment: Checkout section 5.1.3.3 about applying a Sort - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e5655 and have a look at the SortTest in the source code which uses a custom SumFieldComparatorSource - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e5655

Comment: Maybe I'm being a bit dense, but I'm still unsure how to apply this to my particular situation. It seems that the [SortTest](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/b8c78df7403f42ab3f8f73603b01a944cab0a47d/orm/src/test/java/org/hibernate/search/test/query/SortTest.java) you referenced operates on properties of the `NumberHolder` class, where I'd be using a date range that the date on the `Hit` class would need to appear within. Also, how would `Hit`s that didn't fall within the range be excluded? (These would have a 0 count). Or would this need to happen outside of the sort?

Comment: I think I finally have a grasp on how the FieldComparator works. The only thing I'm not clear on is how to get the values out of the document for the number of hits (changed to `downloads` in the code sample to avoid confusion with Lucene hits). It appears that I can create a custom parser to return ints to compare, but it expects a string, not a collection. If I specify `downloads` as the field, it silently ignores it. If I specify a string field, the `parseInt()` method is called. Am I on the right track with the code above, or am I still misunderstanding something?

Comment: It would actually help to see your actual configured entities. Also I don't think you need DownloadsParser.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. I've updated my original question with my entities. DownloadsParser was the only way that I could see to get the ints to compare, since I'm having to get the counts of a collection, and it seems that the normal int parser expects an int field. Although, I'll be happy if there's an easier way to do this.